# How to determinate whose turn is? Card game (tkinter)

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm making Palace card game with 4 players, I'm not sure how should  I determinate whose on turn for throwing a card? Should I use smoething like counter or what ?

Comment: Edited post for more info

Comment: You should not change a question to some other question after it's been posted. Please revert your edit, and put the text from your edit in a new question. But I can tell you that you get the error because you've defined `game_deck = []` at the top of your file, and the `game_deck` you define in your `start` function is discarded as a local variable when the function exits.

Comment: Reverted. Yes, that was problem, fixed it now. thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a simple counter modulo the number of players.

```
class Game(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.count = 4
        self.current_player = 0

    def next_turn(self):
        self.current_player += 1
        self.current_player %= self.count
```

Answer (score 0):

Since different cards may lead to different players having the next turn, and to the game switching between going clockwise and counterclockwise, I suggest you leave the decision to the card object.

```
from abc import ABCMeta, abstractmethod

class Card(object):
    __metaclass__ = ABCMeta
    def __init__(self, color, value):
        """
        Color is either "r", "b", "g", or "y". Value is 0-9.
        """
        self.color = color
        self.value = value

    def is_valid(self, color, value=None):
        return color in self.color or value == self.value

    @abstractmethod
    def card_effect(self, game):
        pass
```

This base class for all cards is the "contract" that a class has to fulfill to be considered a card. Since we're not planning on instantiating this class we make it an abstract class.

```
class Normal(Card):
    def card_effect(self, game):
        game.increment_player_index(1)

class Skip(Card):
    def __init__(self, color):
        super(Skip, self).__init__(color, "skip")

    def card_effect(self, game):
        game.increment_player_index(2)

class Turn(Card):
    def __init__(self, color):
        super(Turn, self).__init__(color, "turn")

    def card_effect(self, game):
        game.toggle_direction()
        game.increment_player_index(2)

class PlusTwo(Card):
    def __init__(self, color):
        super(PlusTwo, self).__init__(color, "+2")

    def card_effect(self, game):
        game.increment_player_index(1)
        game.current_player().punish(2)
        game.increment_player_index(1)
```

For the black cards we do it like this:

```
class PlusFour(Card):
    def __init__(self):
        super(PlusFour, self).__init__("rbgy", "+4")

    def card_effect(self, game):
        color = game.current_player().choose_color()
        game.set_color(color)
        game.increment_player_index(1)
        game.current_player().punish(4)
        game.increment_player_index(1)
```

Comment: Ok, but in this game there aren't skip,turn and plus cards. Just 2 specials, 2 and 10 which are "jocker cards". Rules are simpe, every player has to throw bigger card, if dont he draws all of those cards, with 2 he just skips himslef, but with 10 he removes all thrown cards from game and it's his turn again. I hope it's unterstandable :)

Comment: @Petar If so then this solution is probably overkill. But I thought you said your card game was like Uno, not like [Palace](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Palace_\(card_game\)), which seems closer to what you're describing.

Comment: This is exactly that game. Didn't know  name in English :) Thank you very much